# RxSwift: Nested Queries and ReplaySubject

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, behaviorsubject

I have to fetch three types of data (`AType`, `BType`, `CType`) using three separate API requests. The objects returned by the APIs are related by one-to-many:

- 1 `AType` object is parent of N `BType` objects
- 1 `BType` object is parent of P `CType` objects)

I'm using the following three functions to fetch each type:

```
func get_A_objects() -> Observable<AType> { /* code here */ }
func get_B_objects(a_parentid:Int) -> Observable<BType> { /* code here */}
func get_C_objects(b_parentid:Int) -> Observable<CType> { /* code here */}
```

and to avoid nested subscriptions, these three functions are chained using `flatMap`:

```
func getAll() -> Observable<CType> {
  return self.get_A_objects()
     .flatMap { (aa:AType) in  return get_B_objects(aa.id) }
     .flatMap { (bb:BType) in  return get_C_objects(bb.id) }
}

func setup() {
  self.getAll().subscribeNext { _ in
    print ("One more item fetched") 
  }
}
```

The above code works fine, when there are M objects of `AType`, I could see the text `"One more item fetched"` printed MxNxP times.

I'd like to setup the `getAll()` function to deliver status updates **throughout the chain** using `ReplaySubject<String>`. My initial thought is to write something like:

```
func getAll() -> ReplaySubject<String> {
  let msg = ReplaySubject<String>.createUnbounded()
  self.get_A_objects().doOnNext { aobj in msg.onNext ("Fetching A \(aobj)") }
    .flatMap { (aa:AType) in 
       return get_B_objects(aa.id).doOnNext { bobj in msg.onNext ("Fetching B \(bobj)") }
    }
    .flatMap { (bb:BType) in
       return get_C_objects(bb.id).doOnNext { cobj in msg.onNext ("Fetching C \(cobj)") }
    }

  return msg
}
```

but this attempt failed, i.e., the following `print()` does not print anything.

```
getAll().subscribeNext {
  print ($0)
}
```

How should I rewrite my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

It's because you're not retaining your `Disposable`s, so they're being deallocated immediately, and thus do nothing.

In `getAll`, you create an `Observable<AType>` via `get_A_objects()`, yet it is not added to a `DisposeBag`.  When it goes out of scope (at the end of the `func`), it will be deallocated.  So `{ aobj in msg.onNext ("Fetching A \(aobj)") }` will never happen (or at least isn't likely to, if it's async).

Also, you aren't retaining the `ReplaySubject<String>` returned from `getAll().subscribeNext` either.  So for the same reason, this would also be a deal-breaker.

#### Solution

Since you want two `Observable`s: one for the actual final results (`Observable<CType>`), and one for the progress status (`ReplaySubject<String>`), you should return both from your `getAll()` function, so that both can be "owned", and their lifetime managed.

```
func getAll() -> (Observable<CType>, ReplaySubject<String>) {
    let progress = ReplaySubject<String>.createUnbounded()
    let results = self.get_A_objects()......
    return (results, progress)
}

let (results, progress) = getAll()

progress
    .subscribeNext {
        print ($0)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

results
    .subscribeNext {
        print ($0)
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Some notes:

- You shouldn't need to use `createUnbounded`, which could be dangerous if you aren't careful.
- You probably don't really want to use `ReplaySubject` at all, since it would be a lie to say that you're "fetching" something later if someone subscribes after, and gets an old progress status message. Consider using `PublishSubject`.
- If you follow the above recommendation, then you just need to make sure that you subscribe to `progress` before `results` to be sure that you don't miss any progress status messages, since the output won't be buffered anymore.
- Also, just my opinion, but I would re-word "Fetching X Y" to something else, since you aren't "fetching", but you have *already* "fetch**ed**" it.